# Execute javascript/jquery code OnClick and conditional post back to ASP function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

jQuery newbie question here... I have a jQuery dialog that displays a warning with a "OK" or "Cancel" and based on what they click the result needs to then execute the server side ASP onClick event.

I've attempted to write it along these lines:

```
            "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
```

But it never posts back to the asp server side method.

Am I off base in what I am trying to accomplish here, and is there standard 'best practice' type of way of implementing this type of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `__doPostBack()` method with appropriate `eventTarget` and `eventArgument` to call its sever click handler.

```
  "OK": function () {
       $(this).dialog("close");
       __doPostBack('serverElementId', 'arguments');
   }
```

You can take a look at the below link to understand how ASP.Net postback mechanism works.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to execute the POST on "OK", you'd need to add something like:

```
"OK": function () {
  $.post('someurl.asp', {data}, function() {
    // what to do after the post
  }
  $(this).dialog("close");
  return true;
}
```

As it currently stands, your code just closes the dialog either way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with `asp.net` but you can use an AJAX request to post data to your server-side script:

```
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                url      : 'myscript.asp',
                type     : 'get',
                dataType : 'json',
                data     : { state : 'OK' },
                success  : function (serverResponse) {
                    //you can now access the serverResponse
                },
                error    : (jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
                    //always make sure to handle your errors
                }
            });
            return true;
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $.ajax({
                url      : 'myscript.asp',
                type     : 'get',
                dataType : 'json',
                data     : { state : 'Cancel' },
                success  : function (serverResponse) {
                    //you can now access the serverResponse
                },
                error    : (jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
                    //always make sure to handle your errors
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

Docs for `$.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax